# Visual studio apache cordova remote ios connection hostanme/ip does not match issue

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-cordova, cordova-3

I use Visual Studio Apache Cordova for a hybrid application. I try to connect a Mac computer using remote connection. I made settings correctly. A few days ago, ip address of Mac computer has changed. And ı can not connect Mac computer with remote connection. It gives below error:

> Error: An error occurred uploading to the build server https://192.168.95.26:3000/cordova: Error: Hostname/IP doesn't match certificate's altnames: "IP: 192.168.95.12 is not in the cert's list , 192.168.95.87"

Answer (score 1):

***Try to do following steps.***

- First on Mac terminal give this command

  remotebuild --secure false
- Then find the IP address of the Mac.
- Go to the  Tools->Options of visual studio

  In the Options dialog box, open Tools for Apache Cordova, and then choose  iOS Configuration.
- Give the IP of Mac in Host and Port as 3000. Then put secure mode to false

More details could be found from this link https://taco.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/ios-guide/

Answer (score 0):

> Error: An error occurred uploading to the build server https://192.168.95.26:3000/cordova: Error: Hostname/IP doesn't match certificate's altnames: "IP: 192.168.95.12 is not in the cert's list , 192.168.95.87"

It is a known issue. When the IP address changed, the previously generated certificate become invalid. You can fix this by following steps:

1. Stop the remote agent on your Mac.
2. In terminal run `remotebuild certificates reset`.
3. In terminal run `remotebuild certificates generate`.
4. Change the VS remote build configurations in VS.

For details, you can refer to [Possible issue 2: The host name or IP address of your Mac has changed](http://taco.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/ios-guide/#certificate).